# Dropdown options not visible with jQuery mobile and Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, html-select

I have project with jQuery Mobile and Bootstrap. Until now I succeeded to manage incompatibility but with this I have problem.

Problem is with dropdown (html-select) list, **after first select one option, next time when open list there is no visible options in it**. I guess that there is some css conflict between jQuery Mobile and Bootstrap libraries.

Problem can be solved if I remove Bootstrap from project or change order (now Bootstrap ih behind jQuery Mobile) but I can't do that because lot od other stuff won't work. I would like some fix just for this dropdown element. Could someone help?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7whnhjc5/

```
<!--jQuery UI-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!--jQuery UI Mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select name="status" id="status" data-mini="true">
  <option value="Start">Start</option>
  <option value="S1">S1</option>
  <option value="S2">S2</option>
  <option value="S3">S3</option>
  <option value="S4">S4</option>
  <option value="S5">S5</option>
  <option value="S6">S6</option>
  <option value="S7">S7</option>
  <option value="F1">F1</option>
  <option value="F2">F2</option>
  <option value="F3">F3</option>
  <option value="End">End</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this without CDNs(Online references).
I think this problem due to using CDNs.
Try without CDNs

Comment: I moved all libraries locally and same problem. Nothing changed.